# nodejs require file with function not working in one place only

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform

I'm stuck hours on some weird problem i did tens of this kind operation, but for some reason in one of the files other required files return as empty and the functions cannot be accessed.

here are the exporting file, file name is `"user-repo.js"`:

```
const constants = require('./constants');
const parseRepo = require('./parse-repo');

    const updateEmail = (userID, email) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        parseRepo.getUser(userID).then((user) => {
          if(user != undefined){
            user.set(constants.EMAIL_KEY, email);
            return parseRepo.saveObject(user);
          }
        }).then((user) => {
          resolve(user);
        }).catch((e) => reject(e));
      })
    };


    module.exports = {
      updateEmail
    }
```

and in another file where i want to use this function (`updateEmail`) i do like this:

```
const userRepo = require('./user-repo');
function(){
.....
 userRepo.updateEmail(userID,email);
}
```

and it throws **error** that `updateEmail is not a function`, i debugged this and saw that the required object (`userRepo`) is empty and have no function, the thing is that second before in other file i do the same thing and `userRepo` is working good and have all function.
all this files are in same folder
any idea?

Comment: forgot to mention i have many other require's in this file and all work good the only who not working is this userRepo .

Comment: If I dump the above into a couple of files and comment out the parts I don't have, it works just fine. The problem must be in something you've cut out of the code to shorten it for the question.

Comment: that is the problem, it works second before in other file and only in this one it doesn't, it looks like it simple not looking on the require statment

Comment: There's nothing for it but to debug it. Perhaps your `require` is inadvertently conditional, etc. Use `--inspect-brk` during startup and possibly a `debugger;` statement at the top of the problem module, and step through.

Comment: could it happen because in file A i require file B and in B require A ?

Comment: Yes, see [the modules documentation where it talks about "cycles"](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles).

Comment: ok thanks wiil check

Comment: Do you have any unit tests, which mocks/removes the function?

Comment: @Vivasaayi no i don't have tests but the problem was 'cycles requires' as T.J. Crowder said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was 'Cycles require' thanks to @T.J Crowder for point on this problem and as he said everyone who has this problem please read the docs [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles)